# При загрузке системы появляется UEFI Stop-screen

Tags: bios, asus, recovery, uefi

Собрал компьютер из комплектующих. 
Asus PRIME B250M-K
Hitachi Travelstar Z7K500 500GB
Оперативная память Crucial Ballistix Sport 8GB DDR4 PC4-19200
DeepCool Gammaxx 200T
Блок питания 350 Вт
Процессор Intel Pentium G4560
Теперь при загрузке системы появляется 
"Please enter setup to recover BIOS setting 
 press f1 to run setup ".
Нажимаю f1 попадаю в интерфейс UEFI. 
Если через меню boot выбрать загрузку через hdd, то система загружается. 
Попытки, изменить настройки и сохранить, заканчиваются перезагрузкой системы,
после которой нет видеосигнала, т.е. в в системнике все крутиться мигает, а монитор 0 эмоций. 
Если вырубить питание, достать батарейку, и вставить, при запуске снова 
появляется 
"Please enter setup to recover BIOS setting press f1 to run setup "

В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге оперативная память не была совместима с материнской платой.